# Android: SharedPreferences PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences in Class

Tags: java, android, class, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I want to get a String from my preferences fragment to a class in my android app, but I can't get it like the way I normally do.

Code from my class:

```
public class VtplListContentItem implements VtplListItem  {

    private VtplEntry m_data;       

    public VtplListContentItem(VtplEntry data) {
        m_data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewType() {
        return RowType.LIST_ITEM.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {
        View view;
        if(convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        [...]

        // (this) is the error Context cannot be applied to this class
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 

        String myClass = prefs.getString("UserMyClass", "null");

        // Mark
        if (m_data.getSchoolClass().contains(myClass)) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.accent);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public VtplEntry getData() {
        return m_data;
    }

}
```

I tried:

```
public class VtplListContentItem extends Activity implements VtplListItem {
```

but then I get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at com.philipp_mandler.android.vtpl.VtplListContentItem.getView(VtplListContentItem.java:52)
        at com.philipp_mandler.android.vtpl.VtplListAdapter.getView(VtplListAdapter.java:38)
```

Line 52 is:

> SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

The problem is the (this), but I dont know which context I need to choose

Answer (score 2):

You should instantiate the object passing the context of a Activity as a parameter in the constructor and from there use it

Comment: How do I do that in the best way? :)

Comment: VtplListContentItem you have to construct this object passing the context off the activity that you have instantiated, so for example:
 

`class MyActivity extends Activity {

              VtplListContentItem s = new VtplListContentItem(sampledata, MyActivity.this);


          //And then you can use the context of the activity you have passed       to use in the method you have the shared prefs

          }`

Answer (score 0):

## Pass the context into the constructor

```
public class VtplListContentItem implements VtplListItem  {

    private Context m_context;

    public VtplListContentItem(VtplEntry data, Context context) {
        m_data = data;
        m_context = context;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {
        ...
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(m_context);
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```